# Translate 'Bank Transfer Payment' in Magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

In Magento 1.7, when placing an order, in step 3 there is a paragraph 'Payment method' with the text 'Bank Transfer Payment' (currently my only payment option, so it seems) below it.

Since the webshop I'm working on is not in English, I want to translate the text 'Bank Transfer Payment' but can't figure out how. It's not possible to change this trough Magento's front-end inline translation tool, and I have only been able to find these texts in the files `app\code\core\Mage\Payment\etc\system.xml`:

```
<banktransfer translate="label">
    <label>Bank Transfer Payment</label>
    <frontend_type>text</frontend_type>
    <sort_order>30</sort_order>
    <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
    <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
    <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
```

and `app\code\core\Mage\Payment\etc\config.xml`:

```
<banktransfer>
    <active>0</active>
    <model>payment/method_banktransfer</model>
    <order_status>pending</order_status>
    <title>Bank Transfer Payment</title>
    <allowspecific>0</allowspecific>
    <group>offline</group>
</banktransfer>
```

..but changing either or both labels/titles doesn't seem to change anything.

I have reasonable understanding of XML and PHP. Could anyone please help me out here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried changing it from magento backend system>configuration>Payment methods>Bank Transfer Paymentde

thanks

Comment: Wow, I didn't even see that... My Magento admin panel is half in Dutch (my language), half in English, which is a bit confusing. So I simply overlooked that page. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Based on your locale, theme settings (default locale is en_US) and the desired area (frontend or backend), you can do this in *translate.csv*, e.g.

```
app/design/[adminhtml or frontend]/[PACKAGE]/[THEME]/locale/en_US/translate.csv
```

you would have the following:

```
"Bank Transfer Payment","Desired translation"
```

Comment: Thanks, Faisal's answer did the trick for me but I'll keep your alternative solution in mind for similar future issues :)

Comment: I see what you are asking now. Faisal's is the correct answer for sure.